# where can I find information about my phone by imei

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, hardware, imei

where can I find information about my phone by imei? I want to buy a second hand phone, but I heard that many are declared stolen or lost and after you buy it, police will come and take it away. The phone I want to buy is  htc sensation with android 2.3

Comment: Settings > About Phone > Status

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is [imeidata.net](https://imeidata.net). I've gotten incorrect data from the sites mentioned in other answers.

For example,  for my phone, imei.info gives the wrong data:

> Model: Sidekick LX Brand: T-MOBILE

imeidata.net is correct:

```
IMEI: 3536910674xxxxx
Allocating Body: BABT
Type Allocation Code: 35369106
Serial Number: 749450
Luhn Checksum: 9
Manufacturer: SAMSUNG KOREA
Brand: SAMSUNG
Model: SM-G355H
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for details on a given IMEI, you might want to check with [a post at XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1857054): Here you can find out what the IMEI can tell you:

> 1. The first two numbers is RBI (Reporting Body Identifier) = who registered that type of phone ( verify here )
> 2. The next four numbers is TAC (Type Allocation Code) = what type of unit and its complete specifications
> 3. The next two numbers is FAC (Final Assembly Code) = who manufacture it
> 4. The next six numbers is the Serial Number of the Phone
> 5. The last number is sort of a check sum, that verifies the previous numbers
>
> Combined a total of 15 numbers is used by your network to get the complete information about your phone that is used against their database of Blacklisted phones and final approval to connect to their network, IF they were inaccurate or had complaints (like being stolen, not paid telecoms dues etc) it will be rejected and BLOCKED immediately from connecting to that Network
>
> **You can verify all this by entering you IMEI [here](http://imei-number.com/imei-number-lookup/) and [here](http://www.numberingplans.com/?page=analysis&sub=imeinr)**
>
> **And also [here](http://www.baza-ukradenih-gsm.com/aparativbazi.php) to check if it is blacklisted**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

To find out the IMEI of a phone, simply dial `*#06#`.

Comment: the blacklisting database - looks iffy to be honest - have not seen any mobile provider dishing out blacklisted/stolen imei's... three things about it - the linky does not look "reasonable" - the script looks off-the-wall name - `englishaparativbazi.php` and secondly, how did that get their hands on the imei's that are blacklisted in the first place... thirdly, clicking on 'privacy policy' yields a page that has the word resembling 'poo' as in sh!t...

Comment: also, if the imei is blocked, for example in germany, it can be used in france no problem or anywhere outside of that jurisdiction... :D (Sorry if I'm coming across as sceptical and harsh...)

Comment: but I upvoted for your answer - TIL - never knew what those meant *exactly* - keep *rocking on* Izzy :D \o/

Comment: @t0mm13b That "blacklisted URL" looked strange to me as well. But as all the other information absolutely made sense, plus XDA usually is a reliable source, I didn't strip it off my excerpt. Though, browsing through the thread, it seems that the first URL (imei-number.com) is giving wrong info. So only the second URL (numberingplans.com) seems to be useful. Maybe I should update my answer, and include [imei.info](http://www.imei.info/) to have a second good one? Funny that nobody in that thread complained about your "favorite" :)